# IF Function with multiple statements - If cell contains "0" = "BE", If cell is greater than "0" = "W", If cell is less than "0" = "L"

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

**I'm having trouble trying to get this formula to work.**

I have been using this formula =IF(A2="0","BE",IF(A3<=0,"L",IF(A4>=1,"W")))  But it seems something is wrong as it's not returning the correct values.

So basically, If a cell contains "0" I need it to return "BE" - Above "0" I need it to return "W"
& Below "0" I need it to return "L"

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EHbtNmfZ95TgMuSU8sCx8AWKW2zhH3ubXPGu03P1w9g/edit?usp=sharing

I hope this makes sense!

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Data must be formatted as numbers**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(A2:A11="","",A2:A11=0,"BE",A2:A11>0,"W",A2:A11<0,"L"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will `A2` in every `IF()` clause the drag and down the formula. Also for second `IF(` you can use `<=`, you have to use only `<` (less operator). Try below formula.

```
=IF(A2=0,"BE",IF(A2<0,"L",IF(A2>0,"W","")))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply -
Unfortunately that formula is only showing "W" in all the cells

Comment: I have added a new sheet to your given link. See that. Try to a new google sheet. Formula is completely okay and I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- `IF` formula needs 3 parameters, namely the `condition`, `if value`, and `else value`. You lack the else value on the last `IF` formula so it failed.

#### Fix:

- Basically, we can optimize the formula and only need 2 `IF` formulas here. Why you may ask? Two nested `IF` formulas can already cover 3 conditions. We just need to properly order the conditions so 2 `IF` formulas will suffice.

#### Explanation:

- Since the middle is 0, we need to use it for the first condition. We will first identify if it belongs to which side (negative or positive) so we can minimize the outcome.
- I used negative as my first condition. If `TRUE`, it will return "L", If not, we only have 2 remaining possible conditions left. So we will further check if it is positive. If it is, then return "W", if it isn't negative or positive, then it is automatically 0 and we return "BE".

#### Formula:

`=IF(A2 < 0, "L", IF(A2 > 0, "W", "BE"))`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Optimization:

- I do recommend however that you use `ARRAYFORMULA` so you don't need to copy/drag the formula to every cell. By doing this, you only need to modify the formula of the first row where the data starts. And it will automatically populate the values below.

#### Formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A), "", IF(A2:A < 0, "L", IF(A2:A > 0, "W", "BE"))))`

#### Output:

[image: output2]

#### Note:

- when using `ARRAYFORMULA`, we just need to additionally check if the data is blank since it will go until the last row available if not added.